# Changing the currently open tab in graph editor with Python

Tags: python, scripting, graph-editor

I'm developing an add-on, that sits in the graph editor. I've just upgraded to Blender 2.78 and saw that the panel is divided into different tabs (View, Modifiers, F-Curve, etc.). My add-on is placed in its own tab (mmvt). How can I change the currently open tab to be my tab (in code)?

[image]

Comment: See [this.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6711/get-current-editor-toolbar-tab-via-python#comment10713_6711)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this is possible

Comment: Maybe you should go to stackoverflow

Comment: @Noam Peled exactly where do you exactly where do you want to place that thing in your Add-on or tab?  It's not very clear what you want to do, I do not understand if you want to do something in the add-on tab or if you want it to appear somewhere else!want to place that thing in your Add-on or tab?

Comment: @NikolaTeslaMandici I want (in code) to change to currently open tab from "Modifiers" (in this example) to my addon tab (mmvt).

Comment: @NoamPeled I still do not understand exactly what you want
but deducing possibilities you have to know C/C ++,have a Blender fork in git or github,read the blender documentation (quite a difficult task,the documentation is crap) have someone with experience to advise you and all this just to find the part of code you are looking for,I work in a very light blender version to my liking and even with the experience I have,I can not understand some things they do and how they do,not because he does not know the language,but because it seems that they do it with their legs and not with their heads

Comment: what is not well understood is
your tab is what you show, and you want to change it to where? to be your tab? if that is already your tab !, I'm sorry it's hard to understand is not my native language English

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know. I found this: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Projects/UI/Tab_Guidelines

you have a panel right?
People seem to need a property called `bl_category` be set to the tab page name they want to place it on.
In regard to this question it may be:

`class panelName(bpy.types.Panel):
      bl_category = "Modifiers"`

Also, changing the focus is a completely different task

Comment: Thanks Ruben! Yes, I'm setting the bl_category to "mmvt", this is why the tab's name is "mmvt". I'm trying to see how in my code I can change the currently open tab, so the user will see my tab instead of "Modifiers" for example.

Comment: please note: "changing the focus is a completely different task" ;D
my approach would be:
 - get a reference to a panel inside the tab
 - search the documentation for some Panel.Focus() functionality
 - then shoot it! ;D